# Bootstrapped website gets stuck in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, css, html, bootstrap-4, owl-carousel

My website is getting struck at the start of section. Its getting stuck only in mobile browsers [Website url](https://creovana-217c6.firebaseapp.com)
https://creovana-217c6.firebaseapp.com

```
<section class="home-slider owl-carousel">
  <div class="slider-item" style="background-image: url(images/bg_1.jpg);">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row slider-text align-items-center" >

        <div class="col-md-5 wrap col-sm-12 ftco-animate" data-scrollax=" properties: { translateY: '70%' }">
          <h1 class="mb-4 mt-5" data-scrollax="properties: { translateY: '30%', opacity: 1.6 }">School Affairs Made Simpler by Vicasin Techies</h1>
          <p class="mb-4 mb-md-5 sub-p" data-scrollax="properties: { translateY: '30%', opacity: 1.6 }">Digitalize your school with Daksha. Its so simple, secure and reliable</p>
          <!--<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-5 py-xl-3">Get started</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary-2 p-3 px-xl-5 py-xl-3">Read more</a></p>
        --></div>
        <div class="col-md-7 ftco-animate">
            <img src="images/dashboard_full_1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</section>
```

Comment: The mistake was due to owl carousel version .  I was using old version . I changed it to new version it works without any change

Answer (score 2):

I visited your site using Chrome 70 for Android.
Scrolling was not working when touch is on carousel. You can test that by putting your finger on the chat icon and scroll down, in which case it works.

So, your problem appears to be this:

```
.owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {touch-action: none;}
```

Change it to:

```
touch-action: auto;
```

And scrolling works, but also now user can zoom.
If you do not want multi finger zooming to be an option, change it to:

```
touch-action: pan-y;
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the owl_carousel version, it worked. If u are using old version update to the latest version. The changes said by @Chris Elioglou are included in latest version.